# UWP (Windows 10) application submission failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-store-apps

I am trying to publish an application to the windows store and it keeps failing. The error I receive is the following.
[image]

Could someone tell me what am I missing. There are no input fields in the first three pages to have placeholders. Placeholders in the other pages aren't long.

Answer (score 3):

They mean a different definition of the word *placeholder*. In this case *placeholder* is not meant as specifically an `TextBox` placeholder, but rather a *non-interactive UI* or *incomplete UI*.

To give you an example of such *placeholder* - suppose you are building a restaurant recommendation app and you want to have a navigation feature there which will display a map that will show the user's current location and target location. You want to release a beta version of your app to testers but don't have this map implemented yet. So a placeholder would be if you placed a static image (screenshot) of a map in place where the active map control will be so that the tester sees what the UI *will* look like when finished, but otherwise the feature is missing.

In your case you should check if the first three pages actually work the way user expects or if they are not looking "as if they should do something" while they don't. If you are unsure what to do, post more details about what the app does and what is in these three pages.